# how to properly get JavaScript fetch API status and Twilio SMS Server SID via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to send SMS via Twilio API and everything is working fine.

```
const response = fetch('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    },
    body: 'Body=Hi there, this is a test message from cURL&From=$TWILIO_NUMBER&To=$TO_NUMBER'
});
```

**Here is my issue.**

1. I need to get response status of my api call but it always return undefined as per code below.

   ```
   console.log('response.status: ', response.status);
   ```
2. I need to get **SID (SM7e923758852)** of the server message response from XML file as per code below but not working.

   ```
   var result = await response.text();
   console.log(result.Sid);
   ```

   Here is the Twilio Server Response when SMS is successflly sent

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <TwilioResponse>
     <Message>
       <Body>Hi there, this is a test message from cURL</Body>
       <NumSegments>1</NumSegments>
       <Direction>outbound-api</Direction>
       <From>+18xxxxxxxx</From>
       <DateUpdated>Tue, 19 Dec 2023 12:18:22 +0000</DateUpdated>
       <Price/>
       <ErrorMessage/>
       <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACbec1af2bad9e7829f7bef4c383a025d9/Messages/SM7e92408e42115e87a821f91fb3758852</Uri>
       <AccountSid>xxxxxxxx</AccountSid>
       <NumMedia>0</NumMedia>
       <To>+1xxxxxx</To>
       <DateCreated>Tue, 19 Dec 2023 12:18:22 +0000</DateCreated>
       <Status>queued</Status>
       <Sid>SM7e923758852</Sid>
       <DateSent/>
       <MessagingServiceSid/>
       <ErrorCode/>
       <PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>
       <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion>
       <SubresourceUris>
         <Media>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACbec1abef4c383a025d9/Messages/SM7e9240a8f91fb3758852/Media</Media>
       </SubresourceUris>
     </Message>
   </TwilioResponse>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve the problem.

Issue no 1. occurs because i omitted await keyword before fetch hence

```
const response = await fetch();
```

issue no 2 was resolved by creating **XML Parser** and passing text string to it.  here is the working code

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    },
    body: 'Body=Hi there, this is a test message from cURL&From=$TWILIO_NUMBER&To=$TO_NUMBER'
});


if ( response.ok) {
        const strXML = await response.text();
    var parser = new DOMParser();  
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(strXML, 'text/xml'); 
    var x = doc.getElementsByTagName("Message");  
    for (i = 0;i < x.length; i++)  
    {  
       console.log(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Sid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);   
 
    }



    }
```